pytube not working even after upgrading pytube and pip
I was trying to download audio of youtube video using pytube library but it's not working anymore tried to update pytube still not working.
from pytube import YouTube
YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9j8xuQ6Wc').streams.first().download()

The error I am getting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ideapoke/Documents/financial_analysis/youtube_to_audio.py", line 31, in <module>
    YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL9j8xuQ6Wc').streams.first().download()
  File "/home/ideapoke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "/home/ideapoke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "/home/ideapoke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "/home/ideapoke/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 557, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 749, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone


Instead you can do like this
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube("<Your URL>")

audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

audio.download()

And change the following file in virtual environment folder (venv)
venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytube/cipher.py
locate the function "get_throttling_function_name" in cipher.py
and change its function_patterns to this
def get_throttling_function_name(js: str) -> str:
    function_patterns = [
        r'a\.[a-zA-Z]\s*&&\s*\([a-z]\s*=\s*a\.get\("n"\)\)\s*&&.*?\|\|\s*([a-z]+)',
        r'\([a-z]\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)(\[\d+\])\([a-z]\)',
    ]

How to download audio youtube through pytube source
solution to error in case if you want to use approach that described in first link

Why do you recommend fiddling with get_throttling_function_name and what does that have to do with HTTP Status 410? 410 means the resource is no longer available. In any event, recommending modifying a package in place is almost always wrong. Note: I am using PyTube to download the audio and video streams separately without tinkering with the package. If I specify a YouTube URL that is no longer available, I do get the error, and no monkeying with the package will fix that.

the lib ur using is blocked by youtube so here's a fork that works just fine <3
first uninstall the old lib by doing
pip uninstall pytube

then u install the new fork by doing
pip install git+https://github.com/kszczepanskidev/pytube

and have fun bro <3

Pytube is broken now, try pytubefix instead.
For Windows:
pip install pytubefix
For Linux/Mac:
pip3 install pytubefix
